# Reference tag from pom.xml in properties file to use it in Java

Tags: java, maven, properties, serenity-bdd

Java:

```
    ...
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/profile.properties");
        properties.load(in);
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(properties.getProperty("url") + "<---");
    driver.get(properties.getProperty("url"));
    ...
```

profile.properties file:

```
url = ${webdriver.base.url}
```

Maven:

```
...
<properties>
    ...
    <webdriver.base.url></webdriver.base.url>
    ...
</properties>
...
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>profile.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>profile.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>staging</id>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.base.url>google.de</webdriver.base.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

I want to execute serenity tests in different systems(staging, prod etc.). And for this I'm trying to use profiles in pom.xml, reference `<webdriver.base.url>` tag to a value `url` in `profile.properties`, and then call this value by `driver.get(properties.getProperty("url"));`. `System.out.println(properties.getProperty("url") + "<---");` gives `${webdriver.base.url}<---` in the console(expexted `google.de`). So, it means a reference doesn't work. I have read a lot of topics to this theme and didn't find a solution to my problem. How I can reference a tag from xml to a variable in properties file and then use it in Java? Is it possible?

PS when I hover on `${webdriver.base.url}` in properties file and press `Ctrl` and click on it, I'm getting redirected to `xml` file to `<webdriver.base.url>google.de</webdriver.base.url>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using file from `src/main/resources` and Maven places properties file with replacements into `${project.build.directory}`. So you need to change your java code to use

```
in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("profile.properties");
```